# Issue reusing the same UI Image code across multiple view controllers | Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have the following function I use to customize the navigation bar across almost all the apps view controllers and table view controllers - instead of replicating the code numerous times I am looking for way to easily call the function on those view controllers needing it.

I have tried wrapping in `extension UIViewController { }` but run into a selector issue saying the following:

> Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to local function
> 'Tapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)'

Code:

```
func navBar(){
    
    // Profile Image
    let containView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
    imageView.image = UIImage(url: URL(string: "test.com"))
    imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    containView.addSubview(imageView)
    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
    
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

@objc func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Profile Tapped")
}
```

How can this UIImage be seen in the navigation bar across various view controller without needing to rewrite the same code across all.

Answer (score 1):

Lot a way to do it. I'll usually istance and personalize an UIViewController and use it around the whole app.

```
class baseController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
//call your navBar here
navbar()
}
func navBar(){

// Profile Image
let containView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.image = UIImage(url: URL(string: "test.com"))
imageView.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
containView.addSubview(imageView)
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
```

}
}

Now instance this class whenever you want and your controller will get your navBar() every time with this

```
class mineController:baseController {
//your code here...
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, where should the imageTapped function be written?

Comment: Since you are using a programmatically style you can put it on the baseController.